# Frage zu »3.MANNTOUR«

Tags: meaning, spelling, compound

*»[Der dritte Mann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_dritte_Mann)«* ist ein Film aus dem Jahr 1949, der in Wien spielt, und unter anderem auch durch seine Filmmusik, das *Harry-Lime-Thema*, gespielt von Aton Karas auf einer Zither, bekannt ist. Dieser Film zeigt viele Orte des damals noch nicht ganz wiederaufgebauten Wiens nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg. Ganz besonders berühmt ist der Film aber, weil Teile von ihm unterirdisch, im Wiener Abwassersystem spielen.

Dieses Kanalsystem, dass die ganze Stadt durchzieht, kann an jenen Stellen, die im Film gezeigt werden, von Touristen gegen Bezahlung durchwandert werden. Dazu steigt man gemeinsam mit einem kundigen Führer in den Kanal hinunter, und spaziert dann neben den Abwässern durch die dunklen Tunnel. Ein intensives Geruchserlebnis gehört mit zum Programm.

Angepriesen wird diese Tour unter dem Namen »3.MANNTOUR«, wobei die URL der Website auch verrät, wie »3.« auszusprechen ist: https://www.drittemanntour.at. Also »dritte Manntour«.

[image: 3.MANNTOUR]

Abgesehen davon, dass ich zwischen »3.« und »MANNTOUR« noch gerne ein Leerzeichen gehabt hätte:

- Bedeutet die »dritte Manntour« nicht eigentlich, dass von mehreren hintereinander stattfindenden Manntouren die dritte gemeint ist?
- Ist es korrekt und sinnvoll, *Mann* und *Tour* zusammen zu schreiben? Wäre nicht »dritte-Mann-Tour« eher angebracht?
- Sollte es aber nicht ohnehin eher »dritte**r**-Mann-Tour« heißen? Denn es geht ja um den dritten Mann, nicht um die dritte Tour.

Comment: Dürfen auch Frauen teilnehmen?

Comment: Das ist wirklich verwirrend! Zur Zusammenschreibung: Auf der Webseite taucht auch ‚3. Mann Tour‘ auf, also mit zwei Leerzeichen. Vielleicht ging das für das Schild einfach aus technischen Gründen nicht; oder der Werbedesigner fand ‚3.MANNTOUR‘ ansprechender? Zu ‚dritte‘ vs ‚dritte**r**‘: der Film heißt ja ‚Der dritte_ Mann‘ und nicht ‚Der dritte**r** Mann‘. Vielleicht ist das darauf eine Anspielung? – Das sind nur Vermutungen. Genau wie Sie finde ich das Schild/den Namen unglücklich. Was wohl der erste Mann (also Thomas) dazu sagen würde : )

Comment: @MarkOxford: Natürlich ist das eine Anspielung auf *Der dritteØ Mann*. Das Weglassen des *R*s ist grammatisch aber falsch, wenn der bestimmte Artikel fehlt oder durch einen unbestimmten ersetzt wird. Der Satz »Ein dritte Mann stieg in den Kanal« und die Zeitungsschlagzeile »Skandal! Dritte Mann im Kanal!« sind falsch. Richtig ist hingegen: »Ein dritte**r** Mann stieg in den Kanal« und »Skandal! Dritte**r** Mann im Kanal!«

Comment: Wir sind uns einig, daß ‘Ein dritte Mann’ (usw.) falsch ist – und das wissen die Betreiber der Tour ja sicher auch. Die Frage ist doch also, warum die Tour einen grammatisch eigentlich falschen Namen erhalten hat. Mein Vorschlag war, daß dies zu Werbezwecken geschehen ist, und weil es die Verbindung zum Filmtitel deutlicher macht. – Aber vielleicht habe ich die ursprüngliche Frage nicht richtig verstanden.

Comment: Und nach der dritten Manntour gibt es etwas schnelle Imbissnahrung an der gebratenen Würstchenbude, bevor es mit dem fernen Reisebus zurück nach [Schloß Holte-Stukenbrock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlo%C3%9F_Holte-Stukenbrock) geht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Den Verweis auf das Schloss verstehe ich jetzt nicht. Aber in Wien gibt es keine »Würstchenbuden« sondern »[Würschtlstände](http://www.ostarrichi.org/image-oesterreichisch-28315-Wurschtlstand-Wurstchenverkaufsstand_Wurstbude.svg)«  wird aber meist »[Würstelstand](http://images.derstandard.at/t/12/2010/10/21/1287116296085.jpg)« geschrieben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Den Verweis auf das Schloss verstehe ich jetzt nicht.* – *Schloß Holte-Stukenbrock* (sic) ist eine deutsche Gemeinde, die aus Verheiratung der Orte *Schloß Holte* (benannt nach [einem echten Schloss namens *Holte*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schloss_Holte)) und *Stukenbrock* entstanden ist. Die Schreibung von Bindestrichen suggeriert jedoch ein Schloss namens *Holte-Stukenbrock* und unterliegt damit einem ähnlichen Problem wie die 3. Manntour oder die gebratene Würstchenbude (oder der gebratene Würstelstand).

Comment: Ich mag diese >><< nicht

Comment: @npst es sind ja auch »Anführungszeichen« und keine >> größer-als-Zeichen. Ist sicher Geschmacksfrage, aber angeblich stören sie den Lesefluss weniger als klassische „Gänsefüßchen“.

Answer (score 4):

Abgesehen davon, dass Marketing und plakative Werbung sich nicht unbedingt immer grammatische Regeln hält ("Hier werden sie geholfen", "Sie kann Kanzler") kann man diesen Namen (und das ist einer) nach mehreren Kriterien untersuchen:

1. Namen (und ich betrachte den Titel dieses Angebots als solchen) sind nicht an grammatikalische Regeln gebunden. Alles, was hier folgt, kann man deshalb mit dieser Begründung an sich auch komplett wegwischen.
2. Trotzdem ist die *nicht-Beugung* von "dritte" im Titel der Website im Prinzip erlaubt - siehe z.B. "Totmanneinrichtung" - die an sich "Toter-Mann-Einrichtung" heissen müsste. Da man den Filmtitel original halten musste, um die Verbindung zum Film nicht zu verlieren (schließlich geht es hier nicht um einen beliebigen dritten Mann, sondern um den Titel eines Filmes, der "Der dritte Mann" lautet), ist das wohl auch absolut richtig.
3. Die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln empfehlen an sich, "unübersichtliche Zusammensetzungen mit Substantiven" mit Bindestrich abzutrennen (obwohl man ausdrücklich zusammen schreiben *darf*). Das wäre sicher hier der Fall. Allerdings hat man sich aus Marketing-Gründen wohl entschlossen, durch die Unübersichtlichkeit gerade interessanter zu werden.
4. Korrekte Typografie (nicht Grammatik) würde, wie du richtig sagst, ein Leerzeichen nach dem Punkt fordern. "Werbung darf das aber".
5. Auf dem Plakat links unten sieht man, wie der Titel wohl ursprünglich gemeint war: "3.Mann" und "Tour" sind farblich voneinander abgehoben - Das erfüllt für mich die Funktion eines Bindestrichs zur Hebung der Übersichtlichkeit. Bei der Buchstabenreihe oben hat man das (leider, ich finde die farbliche Abgrenzung eigentlich nicht schlecht) wieder gelassen. Ob das Absicht war oder nicht, kann ich nicht beurteilen. Ich halte es für "einen Unfall".
6. Was ich tatsächlich für falsch halte, ist das Weglassen des Bestandteils "der", ein Wörtchen, das zum Filmtitel gehört. Wenn man ihn schon zitiert, dann lieber richtig.
7. "Der dritte Mann" ist der Titel des Films, auf den wir uns beziehen. Meiner Ansicht nach könnte (sogar sollte) der Titel in Anführungszeichen stehen - Ich denke, das ist ein Zitat. (Siehe Rechtschreibregeln §94/1, "Überschriften und Werktitel")

Folgt man allen Empfehlungen von Grammatik und Typografie, die hier zutreffen, könnte man möglicherweise zur folgenden Schreibweise kommen:

**Die "Der dritte Mann"-Tour**

Was zugegebenermaßen im Vergleich zur gewählten Darstellung einigermaßen langweilig aussieht.

Comment: *Die "Der dritte Mann"-Tour* – Dann hätte man ein Leerzeichen in einem Substantiv. Dann lieber *die Der-dritte-Mann-Tour.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ich finde die Anführungszeichen an sich besser - Damit ist vollkommen klar, dass man sich auf einen Filmtitel beruft. Diese Tatsache wird durch die Bindestriche verwischt. Was in den Anführungszeichen steht ist **ein Filmtitel** - nicht **ein Substantiv**

Comment: @tofro: *Was in den Anführungszeichen steht ist **ein Filmtitel** - nicht **ein Substantiv*** – schon klar, aber *Der-dritte-Mann-Tour* (wie auch immer Du es schreiben möchtest) ist ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv.

Comment: @userunknown Ich will den Marketing-Leuten nicht vorschreiben, wie sie ihren Job zu machen haben - oder ob sie sich in Werbebotschaften zwingend an Grammatik und Zeichensetzung halten müssen. Die Erfahrung zeigt: Sie tun es nicht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Man würde auch schreiben *der "Quo Vadis?"-Plot*  - Wie würdet ihr das mit eingekoppeltem Titel schreiben? *Der Quo-Vadis?-Plot*? Die Anführungszeichen erlösen mich von diesem Problem und sind meiner Ansicht nach erlaubt.

Comment: *Totmann* ist ein schlechtes Beispiel, weil dieses Wort für sich alleine bereits ein etablierter Begriff ist, durch den zwar noch die Herkunft »toter Mann« durchschimmert, aber nicht deutlicher als man z.B. in »Stinktier« ein »stinkendes Tier« erkennt. Nach derselben Logik hätte außerdem aus »dritter Mann« der »Drittmann« (und in weiterer Folge die *Drittmanntour*) werden müssen.

Comment: @tofro: Willst Du mir vorschreiben, ob ich Marketingleute kritisieren darf? Willst Du Journalisten vorschreiben, wie sie ihren Job zu tun haben? Die Erfahrung zeigt vieles - Dieselfahrzeuge werden manipuliert. Ich habe behauptet, dass die Abweichung von den Sprachregeln die Ziele der Marketingleute durchkreuzt. Statt das mit Argumenten zu bestreiten flüchtest Du Dich in eine Metaargumentation und scheinst Du die Arbeit von Marketingleuten zum Tabu erklären zu wollen, das man gar nicht erst kritisieren soll. Vorschriften und Verbote habe ich gar nicht ins Spiel gebracht; ein Strohmannargument.

Comment: Welche Funktion hat denn das Fragezeichen in Quo-Vadis-Plot? Du unterstellst eine Unverzichtbarkeit, die bislang sonst noch niemand festgestellt hat.

Comment: @tofro: *Wie würdet ihr das mit eingekoppeltem Titel schreiben?* Der Quo-Vadis?-Plot? – Ja. Wenn Anführung unbedingt sein muss, dann *Der »Quo-Vadis?«-Plot.* Wenn irgend möglich würde ich Werktitel aber durch Kursivierung auszeichnen, also: *Der* Quo-Vadis?-*Plot* (kursiv×kursiv = aufrecht).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wahrscheinlich würde ich kursivieren auch bevorzugen - Das ist dann aber Typographie, keine Grammatik mehr.